# Width of cell in bootstrap table taking different value then defined

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created table using table class of bootstrap , When i try to check the computed width of each cell it's showing different value of each cell with faded (not showing from where this value is taken.)

I provided a fixed with to cell using the following css

```
#sampletable tbody tr td
 {
  width:100px
 }
```

But when i inspect every cell though it point out to this css specification the width is more than 100px(defined value)

Comment: could you please share a fiddle for that

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then it will take his own css.. try to override the css by using !important then check its working or not.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon (;) in your css. Isn't the problem there?
Please provide a fiddle so we can take a look at it.